# Runtime Error always disappears after clean build

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF MVVM application.  When I start Visual Studio for the first time, and run the app in debug mode, I get an exception as described below.  Following a clean build, the application runs fine until re-starting Visual Studio and running again.

```
'The invocation of the constructor on type 'MyView' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '135' and line position '8'.

{"Cannot locate resource 'views/myview.xaml'."}
```

MyView is a UserControl, exists in the folder it's being searched for in and is contained in the main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a case of a spurious exception, I don't think it had anything to do with not finding the view.  I noticed when I disabled a custom logging mechanism I had set up, the errors went away so likely an exception further up was causing this.